# Shorter way to define classes in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

A standard class declaration looks like this:

```js
class Foo {
    a: string;
    b: string;

    constructor({ a, b }: { a: string, b: string }) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
}
```

Which requires you to copy a variable 4 times -- twice with a type! Might not seem like that big a deal, but it creates needless boilerplate for a very simple task, and is problematic with string literals, as it requires you to have hard-coded strings in multiple places.

The only simpler way i found was using an interface:

```js
interface Foo {
    a: string;
    b: string;
}

const getFoo = ({ a, b }: Foo): Foo => ({ a, b });
```

But now there's need to export both the getter and the interface, which is a bit backwards.

Is there a simpler way I'm missing?

I'd love to see something like Dart's initializers:

```dart
class Foo {
    String a;
    String b;

    Foo({ this.a, this.b });
}
```

**Update:**

Was inspired by one of the answers to take a more functional approach:

```js
interface Test {
    a: string;
    b: string;
}

export function get<T>(params:T):T {
  return params;
}

get<Test>({ a: 'hello', b: 'world' });
```

Which is unfortunately missing default values.

Comment: Maybe give this a read https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#parameter-properties. Also, there's no way to make it any shorter if your constructor accepts an object like that

Comment: Yeah, it's okay with positional parameters, but I'm talking bout named

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to avoid this sort of boilerplate is to refactor it into your own library function (which might need to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to convince the compiler not to complain)

```
function ifaceToCtor<T extends object>(): new (param: T) => T {
    return class {
        constructor(arg: any) {
            Object.assign(this, arg);
        }
    } as any;
}
```

Then instead of making a normal class, you define an interface and make its constructor with `ifaceToCtor`:

```
interface Foo { a: string, b: string };
const Foo = ifaceToCtor<Foo>(); // short!
```

And you can verify it works:

```
const foo = new Foo({ a: "eh", b: "bee" });
console.log(foo.a); // eh
console.log(foo.b); // bee
```

This is similar to your "getter" idea, but this one is a real class (if it matters) and uses `Object.assign()` to avoid the duplication of property names and allowing it to be tucked away into some library you don't need to look at.

---

Similarly you can use `ifaceToCtor` to extend a nonce superclass to add methods or other props not part of your constructor parameter:

```
class Bar extends ifaceToCtor<{ c: string, d: number }>() {
    method() {
        return this.c.toUpperCase() + " " + this.d.toFixed(2);
    }
}

const bar = new Bar({ c: "hello", d: 123.456 });
console.log(bar.method()); // HELLO 123.46
```

And this version has the advantage that what you are exporting is a standard-looking `class`, where the interface and constructor named `Bar` are brought into scope for you without requiring the `interface`-and-`const` from the first example.

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDYBDCBTAKnAwlOAJwB4tEMAPKDMAEwGdE4AjAKw2gD4AKASgC5EYDAHdE3AA6pCqALaCsvRAF5OiMgG8AsAChE+xIQxQQhJBAA2qeo216DDiAnpRCIaEW7SA5oNRgATyU7B1CDAHk2DigAOmt6GG8wbigACxh6ABpEH14Abl0w-QBfQoNinMZ-AIKdUr1dGDBqQjRMRAAxODhEDRzBF0Im72zmAddhxGLapzAXTu6VZDbsPAISLrgefN1dWfngReUhUQW4bj7UQQAiDFTr0ZvmDAxrqZ2dfbgLDBiLOG83EOcDi+UQAHpweRUntnN9fv9AcCYswwZDEM8MLtPlYbIgAELSchUGgMZboVb4IjEPoQcZDMAjRC0QRgECyZ6EKbbXplfSyYypOC0Pi8+xhIwmMyINIZGIQGIEACqEgkGEIuGsGFFAGpEG83nrZfQYrRFXAOjAKBgRQAmD4Oer1WFzKAYonHYRiQmEC6IOn61IYCz-B7MwQARltAGYYgAWACsADZ3jM4T8-gDuMxpDEBWlhXw0VCABIAUQAMhXwogo7G40ndEA)

Comment: Great solution! But it's really too bad can't use Foo as a type though...

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid a lot of var assignment code by using [parameter properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#parameter-properties).
For example, assuming you aren't required to pass an object to the constructor, you can declare the same class as follows:

```js
class Foo {
    constructor(readonly a: string, readonly b: string) {
    }
}
```